# Extract HTML-like tags with PHP

Tags: php, dom, string

I'm trying to extract OUTERMOST special HTML-like tags from a given string. Here's a sample string:

```
sample string with <::Class id="some id\" and more">text with possible other tags inside<::/Class> some more text
```

I need to find where in a string a <::Tag starts and where it ends. The problem is it might contain nested tags inside. Is there a simple loop-like algorithm to find the FIRST ocurrence of the <::Tag and the length of the string until the matching <::/Tag>? I've tried a different way, using a simple HTML tag instead and using DomDocument, but it cannot tell me the position of the tag in a string. I cannot use external libraries, i'm just looking for pointers as to how this could be solved. Maybe you've seen an algorithm that does exactly that - i'd like to have a look at it.

Thanks for the help.
P.S. regex solutions will not work since there are nested tags. Recursive regex solutions will not work as well. I'm just looking for a very simple parsing algorighm for this specific case.

Answer (score 1):

What you're talking about here is making a template. Regex for parsing templates is very slow. Instead, your template-reading/processing engine should be doing a string parse. It's not super-easy, but it's also not terribly hard. Still, my advice is use another template library instead of reinventing the wheel.

There's an open-source template engine in [PHPBB](http://www.phpbb.com/) that you could utilize or learn from. Or, use something like [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/). If performance is a major deal, have a look at [Blitz](http://alexeyrybak.com/blitz/blitz_en.html).

Comment: Reinventing the wheel is exactly the purpose here. I wouldn't waste my time on some commercial project, but i'm trying to learn something here even if it means reinventing the wheel. This is the way i do things for myself. Always. I'd rather know how things work than use something blindly.

Comment: it isn't blind if it's open source :)

Comment: @Marius: Yes, you are free to look at the code and see how it's done.  And none of the template engines listed are commercial products.

Comment: i guess i'll have to look around for that and try to understand something from the code ;]

Comment: Blitz is an extension written in C though. Which I've seen done before as well - very fast. The PHPBB one was historically very commonly understood by designers, since the "html-comment" style plays mostly nice with DreamWeaver, etc, so there's an advantage there.

Answer (score 1):

`strpos + strrpos` (ouch...)

```
$str   = 'sample string with <::Class id="some id" and more">text with possible <::Strong>other<::/Strong> tags inside<::/Class> some more text';
$tag   = '<::';
$first = strpos($str, $tag);
$last  = strrpos($str, $tag);
$rtn   = array();
$cnt   = 0;
while ($first<$last)
{
  if (!$cnt)
  {
    $rtn[] = substr($str, 0, $first);
  }
  ++$cnt;
  $next = strpos($str, $tag, $first+1);

  if ($next)
  {
    $pos   = strpos($str, '>', $first);
    $rtn[] = substr($str, $first, $pos-$first+1);
    $rtn[] = substr($str, $pos+1, $next-$pos-1);
    $first = $next;
  }
}
```

With the `$rtn`, you can do whatever you want then ... this code is not perfect yet ...

```
array (
  0 => 'sample string with ',
  1 => '<::Class id="some id" and more">',
  2 => 'text with possible ',
  3 => '<::Strong>',
  4 => 'other',
  5 => '<::/Strong>',
  6 => ' tags inside',
  7 => '<::/Class> some more text',
)
```

Comment: The OP was talking just about 'outermost' tags. Creating an entire map of a very large template might get big.. this would be a viable approach as long as all the extra memory wasn't an issue. If memory is an issue, you could also just create a map of tag=>location within the string.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time for this. Actually, i've already solved the problem. Looking at your code i can see my approach is probably exactly the same, except it does not make a map, it just replaces the first occurrence.

Comment: allright, not sure how useful it will be though since you've already posted a way cleaner solution ;]

Answer (score 1):

So basically here's what i came up with. Something like ajreal's solution only not as clean ;] Not even sure if it works perfectly yet, initial testing was successful.

```
protected function findFirstControl()
{
    $pos = strpos($this->mSource, '<::');

    if ($pos === false)
        return false;

    // get the control name
    $endOfName = false;
    $controlName = '';
    $len = strlen($this->mSource);
    $i = $pos + 3;

    while (!$endOfName && $i < $len)
    {
        $char = $this->mSource[$i];

        if (($char >= 'a' && $char <= 'z') || ($char >= 'A' && $char <= 'Z'))
            $controlName .= $char;
        else
            $endOfName = true;

        $i++;
    }

    if ($controlName == '')
        return false;

    $posOfEnd = strpos($this->mSource, '<::/' . $controlName, $i);
    $posOfStart = strpos($this->mSource, '<::' . $controlName, $i);

    if ($posOfEnd === false)
        return false;

    if ($posOfStart > $pos)
    {
        while ($posOfStart > $pos && $posOfEnd !== false && $posOfStart < $posOfEnd)
        {
            $i = $posOfStart + 1;
            $n = $posOfEnd + 1;
            $posOfStart = strpos($this->mSource, '<::' . $controlName, $i);
            $posOfEnd = strpos($this->mSource, '<::/' . $controlName, $n);
        }
    }

    if ($posOfEnd !== false)
    {
        $ln = $posOfEnd - $pos + strlen($controlName) + 5;
        return array($pos, $ln, $controlName, substr($this->mSource, $pos, $ln));
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Not an extendable solution, but it works.</strike>

```
$startPos = strpos($string, '<::Class');
$endPos = strrpos($string, '<::/Class>');
```

Note my use of [`strrpos`](http://php.net/strrpos) to fix the nesting problem.  Also, this will give you the start position of `<::/Class>`, not the end.

Why don't you just use regular XML and the DOM?  Or just an existing template engine like [Smarty](http://smarty.net)?

Comment: It won't work, since there might be nested tags. Also i need to match <::Anything, not just <::Class. Can't use regular XML since it's not an xml and i need to replace these tags in a string with specific texts.

Comment: @Marius: Why not change it to XML though?  Also, if you look closely you'll see that the second method is [`strrpos`](http://php.net/strrpos), not `strpos`.  That function finds the _last_ match in the string.

Comment: agreed on the "just use regular XML", and then parse it?

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's strrpos, since there might be two tags one after another. Strrpos would return the ending of the second tag. I've tried HTML, but with DomDocument i couldn't only get the tag as an object, without a clue as for where in the string it resides.

Comment: @Marius: If that's the case, please refer to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348#1732454

Comment: exactly what my answer was trying to say about the deficiencies in regex.. even if you wanted it to work, it would be horribly inefficient, anyways

Comment: I know i can't parse it with regex, i'm not even trying. I want to write a simple parser myself, that is what i'm asking you guys for - pointers to how it could be done.

Comment: @zanlok: Yes, I agree.  Even more-so now that I realize the full scope of the problem.

Comment: @Marius: Pointer: don't.  Use an existing system.

Comment: OK so then .. how? The text is an invalid HTML and i need it to stay that way because it's not HTML at all. I renamed all those special tags to <control> tag instead and was able to find them by loading the string with loadHtml() method of DomDocument (again, i can't use non-integrated libraries). But then ... how do i replace them with, let's say, "[THIS WAS A TAG]" in the original string, without making a mess out of it by adding a bunch of unneeded tags?